# “Compute $dy$ as $x$ changes from $2$ to $2.1$”?

Tags: calculus

I'm taking an [online calculus course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/calculus1/). The course contains the question:

> Suppose $y=x^2+x$. Compute $dy$ as $x$ changes from $2$ to $2.1$.

The given answer is:   $dy=(2x+1)dx = 5⋅0.1 = 1/2$

*(derivitating then substituting $x$ for the initial value of $x$, and $dx$ for the change in $x$)*

Is this correct reasoning?

If so, why is $dx$ equivalent to $Δx = 0.1$, but $dy$ not equivalent to$Δy = 0.51$?

Comment: That is only known to the author of the course. Somewhere there should be a tangent in $x=2$ or setting the difference quotient equal to the derivative in $x=2$. Or some mention of the first-order or linear change of the function.

Comment: The reasinning is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a function $y=f(x)$ we have,  by definition:
$$
dy=f'(x)dx
$$ 
where 
$$
f'(x)=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \dfrac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\dfrac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}
$$

Note that $ \Delta y$ and $dy$ are different things:

$ \Delta y$ is the variation of the value of the function for a variation $\Delta x$ of the independent variable,

$dy$ is the variation on a straight line tangent to the curve at the point $(x, f(x))$, for a variation $dx$ of the independent variable.

So, for the same variation d$x = \Delta x=0.1$ at the point $x=2$ the two values are not the same, since $dy$ is calculated along a straight line and $\Delta x$ along the curve.

The figure illustrates the difference.

[image]

Comment: I've added a figure from http://thewaythetruthandthelife.net/index/2_background/2-1_cosmological/2-1-11_math/2-1-11-12_analysis/2-1-11-12-02_differentiation-of-functions.htm

Comment: Thank you. I still don't really get *why* this is the case though. $dx ≠ \lim_{Δx→0}{Δx}$?

Comment: Really there is a bit of confusion in this notation. i prefer to use $dx$ only for an infinitesimal, but many others use it also dor a finite increment, as in the case of your question.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for clearing things up!